# Firestore security rules using uid from database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I am trying to set up some security rules for my Firestore database, I'm using for my Android and iOS app. My database is open for all users to read and write (to a certain degree), but I don't want the data to be able to be deleted/hacked from writes outside the app, so I need some security rules. What I understand is that: `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null`, is not enough, since it can be easily faked from outside the app.

Here is what I want to achieve. When a user signs in (even anonymously) the app sends his unique uid to a collection in the database. This collection stores all the uid's of all users, where the document name is the uid.

Now in the security rules, I want to only allow read and writes of my database, to users whose uid is stored in this collection. After trying to read about it, I still don't know how to write such a security rule. Could you help? How can I reference this collection field in the security rules, and search if there is a document names with the uid of the requester?

For example, I would like:

```
match /cities/{city} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth.uid = userIdInDatabse()
    }
```

I do not know how to write the function, userIdInDatabase(). This needs to be a function written in the security rules, which takes the request.auth.uid and checks if that uid of the request is in the collection of uid's that I have made from the app. If the uid of the request is in the database, the function will return true. If the uid of the request is not in the database, it will return false. How do I write such a function?

Thanks so much! I hope its clear.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear about writing per-user rules.  Is there something specific you don't understand about it?  What have you tried so far?  Please edit the question to be more clear.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication

Comment: Clarified question more, hope its clearer. Thanks

Comment: Please provide all of the rules, including the code function that you're not showing here.  Also provide the client code that you expect to be allowed or rejected by this rule.

Comment: I further clarified the question. I have not written this function (in the security rules), and the question is how to write such a function. Thanks, feel free to ask further, I really apreciate the help.

Comment: The example rule in the [Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#authentication) section is exactly what you need *match /users/{userId} {* which says *Make sure the uid of the requesting user matches name of the user document.* The only change you need to make is instead of verifying it's that users document, verify the uid exists. See [Access other Documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents)

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot.